# AddColumns is raising delegation warning although i am filtering based on ID numeric field

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-canvas

I have this formula:

```
Clear(colWOSPD);
ForAll(
    colWOSP As wosp,
    Collect(
        colWOSPD,
        Filter(
            'Work Orders Spare Part Details',
            'Work Order Spare Part ID' = wosp.ID And SparePartApprovalStatusSync="Approved"
        )
    )
);

Sum(AddColumns(colWOSPD As cd, "PriceHidden", If(IsBlank(LookUp('Spare Parts',ID=LookUp('Work Orders Spare Parts',ID=cd.'Work Order Spare Part ID').'Spare Part ID').Price),0,LookUp('Spare Parts',ID=LookUp('Work Orders Spare Parts',ID=cd.'Work Order Spare Part ID').'Spare Part ID').Price)), PriceHidden);
```

but the AddColumns() is raising this delegation warning, although i am filtering based on ID numberic field:

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1705340465314.png]

any advice , how to solve the delegation ?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint as data source? If yes, `AddColumns` function is not delegable function for SharePoint data source.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP yes i am using SharePoint